# How to add two functions value to a single input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to How to add two functions value to a single input. It means I have a dropdown list and an input field. I want to add dropdown list value and input field value to another input field. But according to my code, it overrides value. I can not keep both dropdown list value and an input field value. I want to know how can I keep both dropdown list value and an input field value in the second input field.

```js
function changeFunc() {
    $('#currency_name').val($('#cur_rate :selected').text());
}
function click_key() {
    $('#currency_name').val($('#cost_price').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cur_rate" onchange="changeFunc();">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option> 
    <option>c</option> 
    <option>d</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" id="cost_price" placeholder="Enter Cost Price" name="cost_price" onkeyup="click_key();">

<input id="currency_name" name="currency_name">
```

Comment: Make a third function that returns the sum of the returned values from the other two functions and have the element's handler call the third function.

Comment: I would introduce a button that triggers a function that combines the values of both inputs and adds them as value of the `currency_name` input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create other function and add the values or just do conditions in those functions you already have done as I indicate in the snipet

```js
function changeFunc() {
  $('#currency_name').val('');
  if ($('#cost_price').val() !== '') {
    $('#currency_name').val($('#cur_rate :selected').text() + $('#cost_price').val());
  } else {
    $('#currency_name').val($('#cur_rate :selected').text())
  }
}

function click_key() {
  $('#currency_name').val('');
  if ($('#cur_rate :selected').text() !== '') {
    $('#currency_name').val($('#cur_rate :selected').text() + $('#cost_price').val());
  } else {
    $('#currency_name').val($('#cost_price').val())
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cur_rate" onchange="changeFunc();">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
  <option>d</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="cost_price" placeholder="Enter Cost Price" name="cost_price" onkeyup="click_key();">

<input id="currency_name" name="currency_name">
```

Comment: thank you for your effort. But according to your code, it iterates the input field value. Then expected output not shows.

Comment: @user_v12 I think that I miss understood what you were asking. Check now the snipet :)